# Save drawable to string and convert the string to bitmap from the saved string?

Tags: android, uri, android-drawable, android-bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to save the themes. I have themes(images) in drwable folder. I am showing the list of images and on click of the same I want to save the selected drawable resource in sharedpreferences and get the same from sharedpreferences.

To do that I thought to convert the drawable resourse into an uri and convert uri to string.

I tried to convert the drawable to uri like below :

```
public static String getURLForResource (int resourceId,Context context) {


 //use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID instead of R.class.getPackage().getName() if both are not same
    /*    return Uri
                .parse("android.resource://"+ BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID  +
                        "/" +resourceId).toString();*/




    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"
            + resources.getResourcePackageName(resourceId) + '/'
            + resources.getResourceTypeName(resourceId) + '/'
            + resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId)).toString();

}
```

and retriving this uri string from sharedprefences and trying to convert it to bitmap:

```
     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap =
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sharedPreferencesData.getStr(
                            "ThemeName"),
                    options);*/
        /*        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(sharedPreferencesData.getStr(
                        "ThemeName"));

*/
         /*   Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharedPreferencesData.getStr("ThemeName"));

            ContentResolver res = getContentResolver();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = res.openInputStream(uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);*/

            try {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharedPreferencesData.getStr("ThemeName"));

                Bitmap bitmap =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media
                                .getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

/*
                InputStream stream =
                        getAssets().open(sharedPreferencesData.getStr(
                                "ThemeName"));
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);

                URL url_value = new URL(sharedPreferencesData.getStr(
                        "ThemeName").trim());

                    Bitmap mIcon1 =
                            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
*/
```

I tried multiple ways none is working. Either the bitmap is empty or I am getting the File not found exception and malformedException.

Please help with the same.

EDIT :

I get the follwing string from getURLForResource :

D/ImageUri: android.resource://com.dailyfaithapp.dailyfaith/drawable/theme0

I have created a class with themename,font etc... and i am setting values to the same like :

```
      public void setThemes(){


                Themes themes = new Themes();

                themes.setId(1);
   themes.setImage(Utils.getURLForResource(R.drawable.theme1,this));
                themes.setFont("AlexBrush-Regular.ttf");

                themesArrayList.add(themes);

                themes = new Themes();
                themes.setId(2);
            themes.setImage(Utils.getURLForResource(R.drawable.theme2,this));

                themes.setFont("SkinnyJeans.ttf");
                themesArrayList.add(themes);

                themes = new Themes();
                themes.setId(3);
themes.setImage(Utils.getURLForResource(R.drawable.theme3,this));
                themes.setFont("Roboto-Thin.ttf");
                themesArrayList.add(themes);

                themes = new Themes();
                themes.setId(4);
themes.setImage(Utils.getURLForResource(R.drawable.theme4,this));
                themes.setFont("Raleway-Light.ttf");
                themesArrayList.add(themes);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to check the color of the image then why all this hassle?

Comment: Its not just color. I want to save the image as a theme and apply it to main screen @blackapps

Comment: You still did not make clear what you want or what your code should do.

Comment: Please check the edit @blackapps

Comment: You did not tell which value is returned by getURLForResource().

Comment: `sharedPreferencesData.getStr(
                            "ThemeName"`. You have not told the value of this string.

Comment: @blackapps added in edit please check.

Comment: `android.resource://com.dailyfaithapp.dailyfaith/drawable/theme0`. That is a wrong image uri.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213346/discussion-between-sid-and-blackapps).

Answer (score 0):

> you can uri to drawable

```
    public static Drawable uriToDrawable(Uri uri) {


    Drawable d = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream;
        inputStream = G.context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, uri.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        d = G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }


    return d;
}
```

OR do these:

> save bitmap in app root and again read

```
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/images
    File directory = cw.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"bg.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

    } catch (Exception e) {}
   }
```

> Read Bitmap

```
    private Bitmap readBitmap(String path)
    {

    try {
        File f=new File(path, "bg.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        return b;
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```